# How to find number of times a change happens in a matrix, using R

Tags: r, matrix

Let's say I have a matrix

```
 >tmp
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
  [1,]    0    0    3
  [2,]    0    2    0
  [3,]    1    0    0
  [4,]    1    0    0
  [5,]    0    2    0
  [6,]    1    0    0
  [7,]    0    0    3
  [8,]    0    0    3
  [9,]    0    2    0
```

I now want to count number of changes in the matrix, so let's say in the first row I have a 3, then it changes to 2 in the next row and so on. I want to add these changes to a table like this:

```
      1    2    3
  1   1    1    1
  2   2    0    0
  3   0    2    1
```

So it says that 1 changes to 1, 1 time. 1 changes to 2, 1 time. 2 changes to 1, 2 times and so on. I have tried thinking about it for some time, but i can't figure out a smart method. I was thinking of using the function `table()` in R, but i am not sure how to. Does anyone have a smart solution to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: So the zeroes, rows, and columns don't matter (except for the ordering)?

Comment: No they don't matter. Only interested in the change from one row to the next row and to summarise these changes in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t2 = as.vector(t(tmp))
t2 = t2[t2 != 0]
trans = data.frame(from = t2[-length(t2)], to = t2[-1])
with(trans, table(from, to))
#     to
# from 1 2 3
#    1 1 1 1
#    2 2 0 0
#    3 0 2 1
```

You could, of course, skip the data frame entirely and jump to `table(from = t2[-length(t2)], to = t2[-1])`.

---

Using this data:

```
tmp = as.matrix(read.table(text = "      0    0    3
      0    2    0
      1    0    0
      1    0    0
      0    2    0
      1    0    0
      0    0    3
      0    0    3
      0    2    0"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(zoo)
library(magrittr)

tmp %>% 
  apply(1, function(x) x[x!=0]) %>% # Get non-zero element from each row
  rollapplyr(2, I) %>% # Make matrix whose rows are all 2-windows of above
  {table(from = .[,1], to = .[,2])} # make into table
#     to
# from 1 2 3
#    1 1 1 1
#    2 2 0 0
#    3 0 2 1
```

Data used

```
tmp <- data.table::fread("
   a      b   c     d
  [1,]    0    0    3
  [2,]    0    2    0
  [3,]    1    0    0
  [4,]    1    0    0
  [5,]    0    2    0
  [6,]    1    0    0
  [7,]    0    0    3
  [8,]    0    0    3
  [9,]    0    2    0
")[, -'a']
tmp <- as.matrix(tmp)
```